# fire javascript function after partial view is rendered in C# MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC view that after the client click a button a partial view is rendered.

I want to use: `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);` after the partial view is fully rendered, so the client will "jump" to the result of the click.

the thing is: it fires before the partial view is rendered and goes to the bottom of the screen as is before the page height is extanded...

how can I force it to wait untill the partial view is fully rendered?

Thank you!

Comment: are you loading the partial view via ajax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556971/how-to-pause-jquery-code-for-few-miliseconds

Comment: yes: `$('#___').load('/Home/___?departmentId=' + departmentId);`

Comment: I'm curious if adding `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);`directly in the partial view would help.

Comment: @Matt I was looking for a "cleaner" way then using delay or setTimeoUt. Thanx.

Comment: When using `$.ajax()` you have a `done()` handler: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Marthijn tried it. didn't work. don't know why? Thanks.

Comment: @Shlo I use it like this: `.done(function (data) { $('#..').html(data); myOtherFunction(); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $().load your can use the callback to do whatever you want when load is done.

```
$('#___').load('/Home/___?departmentId=' + departmentId, function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply place that

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function ScrollTobottam() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
</script>
```

at bottom of partial view then it will load only after partial view is loaded fully

Comment: Injecting javascript to the page through partial views is just bad design. It's the same crap as UpdatePanel was/is in ASP.NET...